# SQL Server Need to know which rows were created one by one or is next

Tags: sql-server, database

We are uploading a data set from Excel sheet to SQL DB. The Excel file contains records like:

```
1,Supp1,100
1,Ditto,200
1,Supp2,300
1,Ditto,200
```

Now the Ditto in each row matches to the **Supp?** stated in above row. The harm is done as all records are uploaded in DBs with **ditto** values. Now in DB we do not know the actual value of **ditto** within a record.

I was thinking if somehow we can find the time a row was created either by rowid, time stamp etc and then in order which next record step by step. Because if the next row contains '**ditto**' then we should refer previous record Supp? value in the record and change it to same

Any better thought or techniques to do?

Comment: Can you change the load process so that it would assign numbers to the rows that would already then identify which is which?

Comment: This is a problem since rows in a table are considered order-less. If possible, I suggest you add a column in the excel with the row number and of course add it to the sql table also.